# AngularJS ng-repeat to generate TABS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a situation in which a dynamic number of TABS can be created (i.e. the use clicks on an entry within a commands menu and a new pill-tab pair is added to those already existing - NOTE: I'm using Bootstrap for the graphical elements).

The list of tabs is managed within a $rootScope array and, whenever a new tab needs to be open, an entry is added to the array (simple `push` action). Of course, there is an `ng-repeat` that handles the actual creation of pill-tab pairs.

This works perfectly (tabs and pills are added , except that I cannot set the new tab to be the **ACTIVE** one since its creation (i.e. addition to the list) takes place within a controller and the element is still unknown to the DOM.

I thought of setting some kind of timer, but this path is tremendously ugly.

Comment: Where's your code? And are you using [bootstrap.ui](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#tabs) for this?

Comment: I can add the code but it will not add any insight. It is an issue of timing (i.e. element being rendered and only then it can be accessed to set class **active** to it, but the element is still not known to the DOM when it is added to the array within the controller). As per bootstrap.ui, no, I'm not using it.

Comment: I suggest you take a look at my link, it's a native angularjs bootstrap implementation that will make your life much easier

Comment: Thank you @AlonEitan. I have seen that in the past (just had a look at it and things came back to the front of my memory stack). I will consider adding these libraries for additional things I need to do. Still, I don't quite see how this is going to resolve my issue of timing. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that you can use in angular is $timeout service:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout

For example, if you need to do some steps after the directive is rendered and controller is initialized, then just add to the end of the controller code:

```
$timeout(function(){ $scope.steps_to_do(); } );
```

This will trigger the steps after the digest cycle of the component is done.

Also you do have a good control over it in unittests.

So, one possible approach would be:

- before adding a new tab, create a promise in the some parent scope or service
- after the child controller is created, add a promise resolution on $timeout in that child controller

Answer (score 0):

Don't use timeout or anything like this because you never know how long it will take to load it. 
What I suggest is use this directive on your ng-repeat:

```
.directive('onFinishRender', function ($rootScope) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function (scope, element, attr) {
                if (scope.$last) {
                    $rootScope.$broadcast("ngRepeatFinished");
                }
            }
        };
    });
```

HTML:

```
<ul>
   <li class="pages" data-ng-repeat="page in sidebarPages" on-finish-render></li>
</ul>
```

What this will do is listen for last item being rendered in ng-repeat and then fire $broadcast event to the controller. What you need to do then is listen for that event in your controller like this:

```
$rootScope.$on('ngRepeatFinished', function(event, args) {

    // do what you want to do
});
```

You can also try [$viewContentLoaded](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/directive/ngView)

```
$scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function(event, args) {

    // do what you want to do
});
```

Comment: Nice approach, though I would be using `$emit` instead of `$broadcast`. Will give it a try and let you know. Thanks.

Comment: Haven't tried it yet. Don't worry. Once I try, I'll let you know (and vote if it solves my issue).

Comment: I'm just curious :) But it worked for me in the past so should be ok :)

Comment: I know what it is to be curious, and will not let you down. Don't worry. Cheers!!

Comment: Well @TSlegaitis, I regret to inform you that your solution is not working for me. I do get the event fired and captured as expected, but the element is still unknown to the DOM.

Comment: Nope. It is much the same as setting a timer, which means unstable and unpredictable results (since it depends on current performance and load at the client).